# How to send through Html Post Function

Tags: c#, php, html

I have been coding a application in c#, which data is send through get function

Its like this

```
Http://www.myweb.com/co.php?a=10&b=20
```

I am new to c# web programming, so i was wondering how can send the same data through post function. Because if i use $_POST in the php file it dont get the values, i researched a bit and found that POST function takes data in the body rather then in URL.

I just to convert the procedure from GET TO POST. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), setting the [`Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx) and [`ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype.aspx) properties appropriately:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.myweb.com/co.php");

// your choice of encoding, I just picked ASCII here
var body = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("a=10&b=20");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = body.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
    stream.Write(body, 0, body.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanx. Are there any alternate methods without this

Comment: @GreatMajestics: Why would you need alternate methods? This is as simple as it gets.

Comment: I was hoping for a dozens of alternate solution but only get one, still i am very thank ful for helping me. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting .NET 4.5 I'd suggest using [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) if not then I'd go with [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
values.Add("FirstName", "John");
values.Add("LastName", "Smith");
values.Add("Age", "46");

webClient.UploadValues("http://example.com/", values);
```